# Unix sockets: when to use bind() function?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I've not a clear idea about when I have to use the bind() function.
I guess it should be used whenever I need to receive data (i.e. recv() or recvfrom() functions) whether I'm using TCP or UDP, but somebody told me this is not the case.

Can anyone clarify a bit?

**EDIT** I've read the answers but actually I'm not so clear. Let's take an example where I have an UDP client which sends the data to the server and then has to get a response. I have to use bind here, right?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add an example on which I need clarification

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This answer is a little bit long-winded, but I think it will help.

When we do computer networking, we're really just doing inter-process communication. Lets say on your own computer you had two programs that wanted to talk to each other. You might use pipe to send the data from one program to another. When you say `ls | grep pdf` you are taking the output of `ls` and feeding it into `grep`. In this way, you have unidirectional communication between the two separate programs `ls` and `grep`.

When you do this, someone needs to keep track of the Process ID (PID) of each process. That PID is a unique identifier for each process and it helps us track who the "source" and "destination" processes are for the data we want to transfer.

So now lets say you have data from a webserver than you want to transfer to a browser. Well, this is the same scenario as above - interprocess communication between two programs, the "server" and "browser".

Except this time those two programs are on different computers. The mechanism for interprocess communication across two computers are called "sockets".

So great. You take some data, lob it over the wire, and the other computer receives it. Except that computer doesn't know what to do with that data. Remember we said we need a PID to know which processes are communicating? The same is true in networking. When your computer receives HTML data, how does it know to send it to "firefox" rather than "pidgin"?

Well when you transmit network data, you specify that it goes on a specific "port". Port 80 is usually used for web, port 25 for telnet, port 443 for HTTPS, etc.

And that "port" is bound to a specific process ID on the machine. This is why we have ports. This is why we use `bind()`. In order to tell the sender which process should receive our data.

This should explain the answers people have posted. If you are a sender, you don't care what the outgoing port is, so you usually don't use `bind()` to specify that port. If you are a receiver, well, everyone else has to know where to look for you. So you `bind()` your program to port 80 and then tell everyone to make sure to transmit data there.

To answer your hw question, yes, your probably want to use bind() for your server. But the clients don't need to use bind() - they just need to make sure they transmit data to whatever port you've chosen.

Answer (score 15):

After reading your updated question. I would suggest not to use `bind()` function while making client calls. The function is used, while writing your own server, to bind the socket (created after making a call to `socket()`) to a physical address.

For further help look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_core_functions.htm)

[image: Client Server Model]

Answer (score 1):

`bind()` is useful when you are writing a server which awaits data from clients by "listening" to a known port.  With `bind()` you are able to set the port on which you will `listen()` with the same socket.

If you are writing the client, it is not needed for you to call `bind()` -- you can simply call `recv()` to obtain the data sent from the server.  Your local port will be set to an "ephemeral" value when the TCP connection is established.

Answer (score 1):

You use `bind` whenever you want to bind to a local address. You mostly use this for opening a listening socket on a specific address/port, but it can also be used to fix the address/port of an outgoing TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call bind() only in your server. It's needed especially for binding a #port to your socket.